# Is there a term to describe the presence of unnecessary complexity in UX development?

Tags: gui-design, terminology, frontend-development, programming

Here is the case. One client wants us to create a relatively simple website and app (it's just for online courses, nothing extraordinary). We have our dev team, but the client has its own, and they decided to go with **Python (Django) + React/NodeJS + Laravel + WordPress.**

I explained to him that it was a lot of different languages for such a trivial website and that **any of those languages and frameworks would suffice to do it,** and that we should just pick one. But he insists on doing it that way, so be it.

The same thing happened some time ago when we had to convert the website of a large and well-known software company. Since they had thousands of programmers, each one who took the site had a brilliant idea. So *it started with WordPress, then someone thought to use RoR with encapsulated WordPress, then someone thought about using Django encapsulating RoR, which had WordPress encapsulated, then another one thought of using Angular, encapsulate Django, which encapsulated RoR, which encapsulated WordPress*. At that point, it was a Frankenstein, and we were asked to convert that monster into a single language.

Anyway, I thought I'd never see this again, but now it's happening again. Thus, out of these anecdotes, **is there a specific terminology to name this?**

I know it's not UX Debt (UX Debt comes because of this kind of bad decisions). I know of [**Overengineering**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering), but does it apply to UX? I mean, these decisions certainly affect the whole UX process, including UI design. Maybe **UX overengineering** or something like that?

Comment: I call it "Welcome to DEV's world" 

Comment: Does the world still use "Inception" as a reference to things inside of things inside of things?

Answer (score 1):

This won't hurt users granted your flows and UX survive whatever hell your developers go through, but it will definitely hurt your developers.

This is part of DX (developer experience) and not UX.

Your second client, sounds like a classic tale of outsourcing and not double checking the code. Given that the site started as a wordpress site, I'd say they aren't into coding to begin with, so they were ok with what they saw, but didn't know about the hell in the code.

The only other reason I can think of for your current predicament would be microfrontends, or microservices, but I'd have to see how the different libraries are used to know for sure

Comment: While there are obvious UX connotations (some missing features, general speed affected, some FOUC on slow connections), I think you're correct, this is more a DX issue. As for the second client, they're one of the biggest software companies in the world, with thousands of inhouse programmers (that was exactly the problem), they actually got things fixed when they outsourced to us ;)

Comment: @Devin goodness, big companies need to prioritise code reviewing?